# What's with Russia and pull ups?

Tags: pull-ups

Russia got:

A guy who can do pull up with 157 additional kilograms hanging off him, that's  355 pounds, more than most people can deadlift.. On Adam's Raw channel on YouTube

A 7 year old girl who can do over 70 pull up non stop strict Form.

A guy who can do 105 pull up non stop strict form. Just type 105 pull ups on Youtube

Another Russian kid doing 80 pull ups non stop strict form.

Unfortunately I have lost the two kids on Instagram and they are not present on YouTube. But they won many prizes so somewhere there might be a list.

So tell me, did Russia discover a special secret drug which makes you extremely strong at pull ups and nothing else? Are Russian using training methods which can't be applied to other exercises but work wonders for pull ups? Or are Russians built differently?

Cause all their other lifts are impressive, but on THAT level.

I guess there must be some kind of technique there cause I'm also starting to see Athletes from other Slav countries which also speak Russian or similar languages, and those guys are really starting to catch up. So it's either the side blood or they really do have a method.

The best answer I ever got trying to speak with some of them using Google translate was

"it's Bogatyr blood"

Anyone out there who speaks Russian who wants to do the world a favour and try to understand what's happening?

Comment: What's the actual question here? Please be specific, and make it actually answerable. Right now the questions are "what's with Russia?", "did Russia uncover a secret drug?" and "does anyone speak Russian?" all of which are very off-topic for this site.

Comment: If they discovered a method or not

Comment: Are you asking if there's a method to pullups that is actually a **Russian national secret** that somehow not a single Russian person has leaked, and not a single non-Russian knows about?

Comment: This question seemed a bit off, so I googled world records in pull ups. I do not see a Russian dominance even. If there is a secret, it doesn't give them a clear edge. Here is something for you: 4 examples is not a sufficient basis for such a claim. I'd check such theories first, especially if they are quickly googled. Yes, there are some Russians that make Instagram content, but it could be just every social media heavy country as well - just for example. Sone Russians hold records but it's a very popolus nation with many great athletes and others hold far more records than they do.

Comment: I'm closing this question because in its current state, answers can only be speculative in nature. If you have a general question about how to progress in your pullups, see if other questions on the site are similar to what you're looking for, and if not, feel free to ask another question with a more direct and scientifically answerable wording.